# Question on a peculiar limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Take $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be a strictly decreasing
continuous function such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0.$ I would
like to prove that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x+1) - f(x)}{f(x)} dx$$
diverges.

On initial read, we can see that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{f(x)}\, dx
 =\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} - \frac{f(x)}{f(x)} \,dx
 =\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}\,dx - \int_0^{\infty} 1 \,dx
 =\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}\,dx - \infty.$$
Hence, it would suffice to show that either 
$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}\, dx$ is finite or diverges to $-\infty .$
We can see that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} \,dx$$
$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^n \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} \,dx.$$
What's the next step for dealing with this given the strictly monotonically
decreasing aspects of $f$?

Comment: Your approach cannot work, since one example of a strictly decreasing function that tends to $0$ is $f(x)=1/(x+1)$.

Comment: $$ \underbrace{\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} - \frac{f(x)}{f(x)} \right) \,dx =\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}\,dx - \int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{f(x)} \,dx \vphantom{\frac 1 {\displaystyle\int}} }_{\vphantom{\dfrac 1 {}} \Large \text{ This is valid ONLY if }\ldots } $$ $\ldots\,$ the two integrals on the right side are well behaved in the sense that $$ \int_0^\infty \left| \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} \right| \, dx < \infty \text{ and } \int_0^\infty |1|\,dx < \infty, $$ and the second inequality is clearly wrong. $\qquad$

Comment: @user251257 I don't think that's a counterexample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is work in progress.**

If we additionally assume, **that $f$ is convex and differentiable**, then it is true.

Since $f$ is positive, decreasing, and convex, we have
$$ \int_0^y \frac{f(x+1) - f(x)}{f(x)} dx \le \int_0^y \frac{f'(x+1)}{f(x+1)} dx = \log(f(y+1)) - \log(f(1)) \to -\infty. $$

Some remarks:

1. Obviously it is sufficient that $f$ is convex and differentiable on some $(x_0, \infty)$.
2. A non-zero function can't be concave and converges from above to $0$.
3. I haven't come up with a counter example in case $f$ is not convex. So the statement might still be valid.